# Смена стилей при роботе с модулями в ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Мне нужно менять стили от ширены экрана, момент с Store я сделал все данные прихотят , а вот как сменить клас с модулями я так и не понял.

В props.Menu хранить true / false в зависимости от ширины экрана.

```
<header {props.Menu?'className={classes.Header}':'className={classes.HeaderNEW}}'>
```

Этот вариант не работает

Также можно не менять стиль , а добавить клас active , к сожелению я тоже не смог так сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри библиотеку [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) с ней можно просто сделать `classNames(classes.Header, { 'active': props.Menu });`

Comment: а без библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

`<header className={props.Menu && "active"}>`

Если `props.Menu = true`, то будет добавлен класс active, а если false, то active будет убран. Если вам нужно выбрать класс в зависимости от булевого значения, тогда используйте следующую конструкцию:

```
<header className={props.Menu ? "Header" : "HeaderNEW"}>
```

Comment: можно даже без `интерполяции`, например `<header className={props.Menu && "active"}>`

Comment: @Август спасибо, исправил

Comment: Идею я понял , но мне нужно подключить в зависимости от true клас под названием HeaderNew вместо класа Header

Comment: Я сделал <header className={classes.Header && classes.HeaderNEW}> и классы добавились но зависимость от true я так и не смог сделать

Comment: если props.Menu === true тогда <header className={classes.Header}>      \\  если props.Menu === false тогда <header className={ classes.HeaderNEW}>

Comment: @user398213 дополнил ответ

Comment: Идея хорошая , я так пробывал. Проблема в модулях , а именно стиль тогда не работает, модули не применяються . Я новичок помогите разобраться ))                                                                                                                 
 <div class="App"><header class="Header"><div class="Header_menu__Db0Zh"><div><div class="Header_line__1Si8v"></div><div class="Header_line__1Si8v"></div><div